# ios [[self view] center].x

Tags: ios, ipad

on the ipad, when in portrait(not sure if you call it this) the [[self view] center].x value is in the center - but when in landscape(lying down) it is not the center value.

Any idear?

Thanks

Comment: maybe it's still the center but the x and y are inverted i mean..in portrait center is x=384 and y=512 and in landscape x=512 and y=384

Comment: could you post more info on what you are doing to get this issue? posting some code and values will help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `center` property of a view is relative to its `superview`, which is probably the `UIWindow` in your case. Since rotation is handled by the view controller and the window actually doesn't rotate, the `center` of your view stays the same.

What you probably want instead is the center of your view's bounds:

```
CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
CGPoint centerOfView = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
```